# Status "pending" after successful purchase + callback not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm using a paypal button on my website

```
<script src="/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=johndoe@gmail.com" 
                data-button="buynow" 
                data-name="Item1" 
                data-quantity="1" 
                data-amount="1.99" 
                data-currency="EUR" 
                data-shipping="0" 
                data-tax="0" 
                data-callback="http://www.example.com/checkout" 
                data-env="sandbox"
                data-lc="de_DE"
            ></script>
```

which is working fine. I get redirected to the paypal checkout and my checkout controller (callback url) is fetching the IPN + writes it in my rails model.

Two issues I have here:

1. The payment status is always "pending". I get the IPN message 3 times after the checkout. I tried solving this by changing my sandbox account to an EUR account as read here in the forum but that did not solve the issue. IPN keeps coming in until a total of 7 per purchase. Status is always "pending" although the transaction was displayed as completed / paid to the merchant.
2. The callback redirect is somehow not working. I am expecting the sandbox to redirect me to my callback URL or at least display some button "back to the website" but nothing is showing up. The only link I see after my purchase is "to my PayPal account" or similar. Why is there no automatic redirect or at least a link back to my website?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I managed to get the status completed after manually creating a new button via a new sandbox merchant. It turned out that I used an old sandbox merchant account who was US and not working properly. 

Now I still have the problem that I get the IPN message 3 times and it wont stop notifying me.

Is there any easy way for my rails controller to give Paypal a 200 after status completed was sent?

Answer (score 0):

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 200
```